# Display image based on a query result in asp GridView

Tags: asp.net

i am looking for a way that:
If the Gridview contains a result, don't show the result but instead an clickable image that will direct me to a new page with the result(this i guess in the properties of the image).
And if the gridview is empty, then display another image.
I know how to do it if the gridview is empty i use

But i would like to know **how to show an image if gridview is not empty**.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: If don't want to show the data and has to show an image instead, why do you the grid view at all. You can simply use an image (or hyperlink) based on the record count based on your data
if(recordcount > 0)
{
// show image
}
else 
{
// show another image
}

Comment: aravind is right. Read up on the Data List or Data Repeater. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

Comment: Hi, i didn't know about  record count. I am a windows sysadmin who got asked to create an ASP page, so it is the first time i look into ASP and C#. Thanks for the tip, I will look into it. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}  {7}8}",Eval("CourseName"),"/","Colleges","/",Eval("StateName").ToString().Replace(" ", "-"),"/",Eval("CityName").ToString().Replace(" ", "-"),"/",Eval("CollegeName").ToString().Replace("-", "=").Replace(" ", "-").Replace("..","--")) %>' rel="canonical" title='<%# Eval("CollegeName")%>'>
            <img Height="50px" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}","\\images\\CollegeImages\\" , string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CollegeImage").ToString()) ?"noImageCollege.jpg":Eval("CollegeImage")) %>' Width="50px" alt='<%# Eval("CollegeName") %>' title='<%# Eval("CollegeName") %>' />
</a>
```

Comment: Hi naval, can you please explain how i implement this?? Thanks

Comment: bind the value in the href based on the condition and check the condition while binding the value in the href value